# Android Spinner Adapter Setting to spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm using eneter framework to process communication in my android application;
the problem is when **I'm trying to populate a spinner, setting the adapter to the spinner cause an undefined exception**

Here the code

```
public void populateSpinner(TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<String> arg1){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String listf = arg1.getResponseMessage();
    //sendToDebug(listf);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(listf,",");
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
        list.add((String)tokenizer.nextElement());
    }
    //EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2EditText);
    //text.setText(list.size());
    //text.setText(listf);
    Spinner forfait = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.forfaitsSpinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    forfait.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you get?

Comment: Which type of error you got? And which line?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

you are passing `this` in the following piece of code,

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

Not sure in which block this code lies or which class, but ensure that **`this`** refers to `ActivityName.class` or  `the context`

Comment: It's an activity bro, i was populating the spinner in a method that is called when an event is fired, that was the problem, populating the spinner in the doCreate() method solved it, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you are using an `ArrayAdapter` rather than a `SpinnerAdapter`.  `ArrayAdapter` is an indirect implementer of the `SpinnerAdapter` interface rather than one which declares that it implements the interface.  Check the undefined exception.  It is likely telling you that `setAdapter(ArrayAdapter)` is not defined for `Spinner`.

Comment: You can definitely use an array adapter with a spinner sir

Comment: :-)  I agree that it should be possible, but without the complete backtrace we're left to speculation.

Comment: Thank you brother, my problem was that i want to populate the spinner when an event is fired, i modified my desing making the spinner populated in another activity in the onCreate() method and belonging to another layout, it works now. Thnak you !