# populating spinner with data from database

Tags: android, mysql

what i am trying to do is to first insert some values in the database(see insertvalues function) and then retrieving all the data from database into the spinner(see getvalues function).i successfully retrieve data from database which i checked through the textboxes.but when i set this data to my spinner adapter and run the app,i get an empty spinner.i understand that i should first write the line 
My_spinner=(spinner)findViewbyid(--) and then call the getvalues function,but when i try to move this line(My_spinner=(spinner)findViewbyid(--) somewhere else,my app does not work anymore and says unfortunately the app was closed.i took quite alot of time to figure out the problem but i could not,please help.

package com.example.gcmclientapp;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class GcmServer extends Activity {


     void showToast(CharSequence msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    // declarations for creating the database
    SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    String name_from_spinner;  // this will be used to filter the database for the required registrationID
    private   static String DBNAME = "new1.db";  // this is our database..change it when you use
    private static String TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    //end of dec








    EditText et;
    String regId,userName;
    Button b;
    TextView tv,tv2;
    String temp="";
    String[] arr;
    Spinner My_spinner;
    InputStream is=null;

    ArrayList<String> my_array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gcmserver);
        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        regId = getIntent().getStringExtra("REGID");
        userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER");



          insertvalues();

          getTableValues();
          My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);








        //setting on click listeners for the items of the spinner

        My_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        name_from_spinner=my_array1.get(position);
                        showToast(name_from_spinner);// get the name that has been clicked in the spinner





                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        showToast("Please enter contact");

                    }
                });







        // when the send button is clicked,we will extract the message from editText,regID and send to sendtoserver

        // send button
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String ID = null;
                String REGID=null;
                String NAME=null;
                String message =et.getText().toString(); //extract message from edit text
                // extract registration number
                 try {

                    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    Cursor allrows = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);
                    if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                             ID = allrows.getString(0);
                             REGID = allrows.getString(1);
                             NAME = allrows.getString(2);
                             if(NAME.equals(name_from_spinner)) // string comparison
                             {

                                 break;
                             }

                        } while (allrows.moveToNext());

                        showToast("left loop");


                    }



                    allrows.close();
                    mydb.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                 //tv.setText(REGID);
                 System.out.print(REGID);
                sendToServer(message,REGID);
            }

        }); 

    }



    //#########################################INSERT############################################################
    public void insertvalues()
    {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", regId));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", userName));

    try {
          //tv2.setText(regId);
          HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/new.php");
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
          is=entity.getContent();
          showToast("data inserted successfully");






    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {

         Log.e("clientProtocol","Log_tag");
         e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag","ioexception");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }


    public void sendToServer(final String message,final String ID){
        //tv2.setText(ID);
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>(){
        // changes are needed here
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpResponse response = null;
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                String url="http://192.168.1.3/GCM/gcm.php?" + "&regID="+ ID + "&message="+ message; // changes needed here
                Log.i("Send URL:", url);
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

                response = client.execute(request);
                Log.i("responce URL:"," ");
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String webServiceInfo = "";
                while ((webServiceInfo = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("****Status Log***", "Webservice: " + webServiceInfo);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
   }.execute(null,null,null);
  }
















 // ################################THIS FUNCTION SHOWS DATA FROM THE DATABASE#####################################
    public void getTableValues() {

        InputStream iss=null;
        String line=null;
        String result=null;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        try {

              HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/retrieve.php");

              HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
              iss=entity.getContent();


              }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {

             System.out.println("exception 1  caught");

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag","ioexception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)

                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                        result=sb.toString();
                        //result now contains the data in the form of json
                        iss.close();
                        System.out.println("here is my data");
                        System.out.println(result);




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception 2 caught");
        }

        try{

            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);
            int count=jArray.length();

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                temp+=json_data.getString("name")+":";



            }
            //System.out.println(temp);
            arr=temp.split(":");
            tv.setText(arr[1]);
            tv2.setText(arr[2]);



            ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    arr);

            My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("m so boread");
            //System.out.println("hello");
        }



    }

  //###############################################################################################################  
 }
```

// log cat after editing the code as suggested

01-17 21:27:32.939: D/dalvikvm(1895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 172K, 3% free 9493K/9692K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-17 21:27:33.019: W/EGL_genymotion(1895): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-17 21:27:33.075: D/AndroidRuntime(1895): Shutting down VM
01-17 21:27:33.075: W/dalvikvm(1895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4be7648)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at com.example.gcmclientapp.GcmServer$1.onItemSelected(GcmServer.java:123)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-17 21:27:33.075: E/AndroidRuntime(1895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Try to populate values into the Spinner, not inside any other method, but inside the onCreate() method. Try to change your program as belows:

Change the getTableValues() method as:

```
public String[] getTableValues() {
```

Remove these lines from that method:

```
ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);

My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
```

And return the array "arr" at the end of the method;

```
return arr;
```

and then populate values to Spinner at the onCreate() method after initializing the My_spinner object as belows

```
My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
arr = getTableValues();
ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);

My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
```

Comment: i tried to do as you suggested and now my app shuts down, please check the logcat above :(

Comment: Try to return a List instead of a String[].. as I think the same problem is asked here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021565/android-spinner-adapter-setting-to-spinner

Comment: Have a .... List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); ... in your method and add the "name" values to the list instead of splitting them and building an array. Then you can return the list and get it from onCreate() and initialize the Adapter using the list (not with arr) set the Adapter to Spinner.

Comment: can you please write a bit of a code for me?i am a newbie,shall be really thankful

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this code working as I cannot debug this at the moment. It's a pleasure to help with this...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class GcmServer extends Activity {


     void showToast(CharSequence msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    // declarations for creating the database
    SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    String name_from_spinner;  // this will be used to filter the database for the required registrationID
    private   static String DBNAME = "new1.db";  // this is our database..change it when you use
    private static String TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    //end of dec








    EditText et;
    String regId,userName;
    Button b;
    TextView tv,tv2;
    String temp="";
    String[] arr;
    Spinner My_spinner;
    InputStream is=null;

    ArrayList<String> my_array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gcmserver);
        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        regId = getIntent().getStringExtra("REGID");
        userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER");



          insertvalues();


          My_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

          List<String> list = getTableValues();

          ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

          My_spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);







        //setting on click listeners for the items of the spinner

        My_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        name_from_spinner=my_array1.get(position);
                        showToast(name_from_spinner);// get the name that has been clicked in the spinner





                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        showToast("Please enter contact");

                    }
                });







        // when the send button is clicked,we will extract the message from editText,regID and send to sendtoserver

        // send button
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String ID = null;
                String REGID=null;
                String NAME=null;
                String message =et.getText().toString(); //extract message from edit text
                // extract registration number
                 try {

                    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    Cursor allrows = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE, null);
                    if (allrows.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                             ID = allrows.getString(0);
                             REGID = allrows.getString(1);
                             NAME = allrows.getString(2);
                             if(NAME.equals(name_from_spinner)) // string comparison
                             {

                                 break;
                             }

                        } while (allrows.moveToNext());

                        showToast("left loop");


                    }



                    allrows.close();
                    mydb.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                 //tv.setText(REGID);
                 System.out.print(REGID);
                sendToServer(message,REGID);
            }

        }); 

    }



    //#########################################INSERT############################################################
    public void insertvalues()
    {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", regId));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", userName));

    try {
          //tv2.setText(regId);
          HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/new.php");
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
          HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
          is=entity.getContent();
          showToast("data inserted successfully");






    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {

         Log.e("clientProtocol","Log_tag");
         e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag","ioexception");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }


    public void sendToServer(final String message,final String ID){
        //tv2.setText(ID);
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>(){
        // changes are needed here
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                HttpResponse response = null;
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                String url="http://192.168.1.3/GCM/gcm.php?" + "&regID="+ ID + "&message="+ message; // changes needed here
                Log.i("Send URL:", url);
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

                response = client.execute(request);
                Log.i("responce URL:"," ");
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String webServiceInfo = "";
                while ((webServiceInfo = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("****Status Log***", "Webservice: " + webServiceInfo);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
   }.execute(null,null,null);
  }
















 // ################################THIS FUNCTION SHOWS DATA FROM THE DATABASE#####################################
    public List<String> getTableValues() {

        InputStream iss=null;
        String line=null;
        String result=null;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        try {

              HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/retrieve.php");

              HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
              iss=entity.getContent();


              }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {

             System.out.println("exception 1  caught");

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag","ioexception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)

                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                        result=sb.toString();
                        //result now contains the data in the form of json
                        iss.close();
                        System.out.println("here is my data");
                        System.out.println(result);




        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception 2 caught");
        }

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try{

            JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(result);
            int count=jArray.length();

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(json_data.getString("name"));
            }
            //System.out.println(temp);
            tv.setText(arr[1]);
            tv2.setText(arr[2]);


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("m so boread");
            //System.out.println("hello");
        }

        return list;

    }

  //###############################################################################################################  
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much,i will try this , that was really kind of you :)