# Android Spinner no items shown only arrow

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, spinner

Hey I already checked a lot of other questions about this problem but all the over solutions didn't helped. So my problem is that I also just see the arrow of a spinner and no items are shown.
So I have two spinners actually but their code is the same so didn't posted the other one. Hopefully someone has an idea how to fix this issue. Would be greatful for every idea!

Code:

```
      var speedAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.speedByte,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )

    speedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    this.speedSpinner.adapter = speedAdapter
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        />


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/speedTab"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_download" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pingTab"
            android:text="@string/tab_text_ping" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="6"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"

        >

        <Switch
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:text="@string/bit_byte"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/sizeBitByteSwitcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <Switch
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/bit_byte"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/speedBitByteSwitcher"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="@string/note_size"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textEditSize"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Space
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="@string/note_speed"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textEditSpeed"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sizeSpinner"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
            android:foreground="#000000"

            />

        <Space
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_column="1" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/speedSpinner"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
            />


    </GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calcBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/calc_btn"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speedResultView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="RESULT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is also now the array resource:

```
<string-array name="speedByte">
    <item name="Byte">Byte /s</item>
    <item name="Kilo">KiloByte /s</item>
    <item name="Mega">MegaByte /s</item>
    <item name="Giga">GigaByte /s</item>
    <item name="Terra">TerraByte /s</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Post this `R.array.speedByte`.

Comment: What do I have to change on that?

Comment: Please provide array.xml. I think the way you provided array is problematic

Comment: added the array file

Comment: There are no errors? Can you post more code, so we can reproduce it? The other spinner works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct and it worked for me, but I am not able to see the spinner until I have changed `layout_height` to `wrap_content`. Currently it is `0dp` I guess that's why It's not visible.

But if you still face this issue then I will suggest you to conform that your following code is executed.

```
this.speedSpinner.adapter = speedAdapter
```

Comment: Ah it was the wrap content which fixed it, also needs some more height so gonna have to give it more space, thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

After implementing your code I was able to see the items. Where have you put the string array? It should be in the strings.xml file.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string-array name="speedByte">
        <item name="Byte">Byte /s</item>
        <item name="Kilo">KiloByte /s</item>
        <item name="Mega">MegaByte /s</item>
        <item name="Giga">GigaByte /s</item>
        <item name="Terra">TerraByte /s</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Also increase the height of the Spinner to make it more clickable.

Comment: I also have it in the stings.xml

Comment: @Schmidi Are you able to see the items now?

Answer (score -1):

Just add entries attribute to your xml:

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/speedSpinner"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:entries="@array/speedByte"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:gravity="fill"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
                />
```

Comment: Can you try and instantiate your ArrayAdapter like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024788/12262856

Comment: @StefanPerlic nice suggestion.

Comment: Also didn't worked, do you think more code or anything else is needed to show to find the problem?

Comment: Just give me the repo, I'll run it

Answer (score -1):

Try this.It should work :
first get your string array and cast it to List

```
    String[] speedByte= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.speedByte);
    List<String> lstSpeedByte = Arrays.asList(speedByte);
```

Then pass the list to ArrayAdapter:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(your context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstSpeedByte );


    speedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    speedSpinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
```